# How do I change the auto complete hotkey for GitHub Copilot suggestion in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I change the auto complete hotkey for GitHub Copilot suggestion in Visual Studio 2022?

[image]

In a previous version of Copilot, the hotkey conflicted with Visual Studio's IntelliCode, they would both fight for the [TAB] key, so I set GitHub Copilot to use the Right Arrow key instead.
This issue has now been resolved, so I would like to change the hotkey back but I am unable to figure out how to change the auto complete key.

I have searched in Visual Studio> Options> Environment> Keyboard area.

My assigned hotkey is not under "copilot" or "complete" or "suggest".

Comment: under `Tools > Options > IntelliCode > Advanced`, untick `Apply whole line completions on right arrow` checkbox.


Just note it's `IntelliCode` not `Intellisense` when navigating the options to get to the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Under **Tools > Options > IntelliCode > Advanced**, untick **Apply whole line completions on right arrow** checkbox. Just note it's *IntelliCode* not *Intellisense* when navigating the options to get to the checkbox.

(originally answered by @H7O in comments)